# How to make browser auto focus on Flash form

Tags: browser, flash

Where I work we have an application that uses flash to display a form.  The form element we want is "auto focused" however in order to use the thing we have to click somewhere in the flash object first.  Is there any way around this?  Preferably a fix for IE 8. I myself am using Chrome and have to do the same (clicking first) so it is not a browser based problem.  Most of my users have to use IE for other programs (program specific ActveX stuff).

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use ExternalInterface to sendFocus to Flash based on a tab key handler in Javascript, but looking at the date of you post, I'm guessing you know that now!